Why I'm getting iOS App archive wrong runner?
I am trying to build app for an update on the store, but in Xcode, instead of archiving the expected runner application, the archive is successfully created, yet it is not associated with the correct runner. As a result, I am unable to upload and distribute the app to the store after the build.
I have been trying every possible solution, but I cannot identify what is wrong or causing the problem. Kow to resolve this?
Before I managed to do like this:

Now not able to get the correct runner build

Not able to distribute the app


Please read a tag's description before using that tag.

I managed to find a solution, just add this to your PodFile, under post_install:
unless target.name == 'Runner'
    config.build_settings['SKIP_INSTALL'] = "YES"
  end

This fixed my problem 100%
